# Where can I find the proof of trigonometrical functions for complementary angles.

Tags: trigonometry

For example sin a=cos(90-a), sin a=cos(90-a)...

[image]

I found it in one book, but I can't find it anywhere. Can you tell me a website where I can find the proof?

Comment: You can look for 'cofunction identities'. For example, https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=cofunction+identities+proof

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough with the unit-circle definition of the trigonometric functions:

Just mirror the diagram around the line $x=y$. The $x$-coordinate of the point on the unit circle (that is, the cosine) turns into the $y$-coordinate (that is, the sine) and vice versa, while the angle with the $x$-axis changes from the original angle to its complement.